# md-date-picker not showing current month AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using Angularjs md-datepicker for calendar.
When I click the date picker, I want the current month to be displayed.
But the datepicker is not showing the current month.

Can you find whats wrong with my code? Thanks

```
<div class="col-md-3" style="margin: 18px 0;">
    <md-datepicker ng-model="formData.startAt1" ng-required="true" md-max-date="formData.endAt1" md-placeholder="Enter start date">
    </md-datepicker>
    <div class="row" id="startDateError" style="display: none">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="color: #FF5252;margin-top: 6px;font-weight: 600;">* Please select start date.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
scope.formData = {
       startAt1: "",
       endAt1: ""
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no md-model, it should be ng-model,

```
   <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

**DEMO**

```js
angular.module('datepickerBasicUsage', ['ngMaterial'])
.controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope) {
  
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="datepickerBasicUsage">

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.js"></script>
  <script src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/t-114/assets-cache.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.0.4/angular-material.css">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;'>
    <form ng-submit='angular.noop'>
      <md-content>
        <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
        <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
      </md-content>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: i remember i saw it :P , anyhow is this what you require?

Comment: @Sajeerthan..Yes same as the demo.But I have done the same thing.Not working

Comment: can you tell what is the mistake?

Comment: you could check the model variable

Comment: I initialized model var as "" initially

Comment: dont have a empty string, have it as  startAt1: new Date(),

Comment: Okay,I will try @Sajeetharan